# why does a variable need to be created in this closure

Tags: javascript, function, variables, closures

Hi I have the following closure

```
    function createCounter() {
       var numberOfCalls = 0;
       return function() {
          return ++numberOfCalls;
       }
    }

 var fn = createCounter();
fn()
fn()
```

And I believe I understand about scope and the fact that the inner function keep the outer function's values after the outer one has returned.

What I don't understand is why I need to create this variable

```
var fn = createCounter()
```

and then invoke the variable `fn()` instead of initially invoking `createCounter()`

I saw that  createCounter() just returns 'function()' instead of what has to be '1' and I don't understand why.

Thanks for the help. Read many tutorials still having problems with understanding this.

Please note: the question's isn't about how to make the code more eloquent or better, it's about understanding of what's been done

Comment: Why do you expect `createCounter` to return `1` when it clearly returns a function?

Comment: @Why do you expect createCounter to return 1 when it clearly returns a function? The inner function itself returns a value that should be '1', so should not the outer function return the value of the inner one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `createCounter` is called it returns another function and that returned function is not evaluated unless you do so. Remember, in JavaScript functions are objects too. They can be the return value of a function.

So when you do this:

```
var fn = createCounter();
```

`fn` references only the function returned by `createCounter`function and not its evaluated value.

If you need to evaluate the function returned by `createCounter` try something like:

```
createCounter()();
```

This evaluates the returned function.

If you call it like this it will always return the same value as it creates a new `numberOfCalls` variable every time you call `createCounter`.

Comment: Thanks, I've been having issues with understanding closures for days because of thinking inner functions are to be evaluated when outer ones are invoked

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, functions are objects which can be passed to and returned by other functions, as any other objects (e.g. a string, a number...).

So doing:

```
function foo(arg) { /* ... */ }
var someObject = new String("Hello");
foo(someObject);
```

is similar as:

```
function foo(arg) { /* ... */ }
var someFunction = new Function("Hello", "...");
foo(someFunction);
```

A function may thus return another function, which can be invoked as needed.

```
function foo() {
   return new Function(...);
}
var functionReturnedByCallingFoo = foo();
functionReturnedByCallingFoo(); // can be invoked
functionReturnedByCallingFoo(); // and again
functionReturnedByCallingFoo(); // and again
```

Now, functions are almost never declared using the Function constructor, but rather with constructs named "function declarations" or "function expressions" - basically, the way we have defined the function "foo" in the previous examples, with a function signature and a function body delimited by curly brackets.

In such cases, the statements inside of the function body can read and write variables declared outside of the function itself ("free variables"), and not only variables declared within the function, as per the rules of lexical scoping. This is what we call a closure.

So in your case, the createCounter() function, when invoked, defines a local variable named "numberOfCalls", then return a function - the body of which having access to that variable. Executing the returned function changes the value of the variable, at each invocation, as it would for any "global" variable (i.e. variables declared in outer scopes).

Executing the createCounter() function many times would simply, each time, recreate a new local variable "numberOfCalls", initialize it to zero, and return a new function object having access to that variable.